# check_password() returning False

Tags: django, django-authentication

I have made a model with its own password field. This is wholly separate from the `User` object. I'm using the `django.contrib.auth.hashers` library for this.

In the create method for this model (overwriting a generic CreateListAPI view)

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = request.data
        data['password'] = make_password(data['password'])
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

This stores a hashed password in my database as expected, but when I try to authenticate with the password

```
def get_object(self):
    queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())

    try:
        # Grabs the 'name' parameter from the URL
        obj = queryset.get(name=self.kwargs['name'])
    except Group.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404

    print(self.request.data['password'])  # raw password string
    print(obj.password)  # encoded password from database
    if check_password(self.request.data['password']), obj.password):
        raise Http404

    obj.user_set.add(self.request.user)

    self.check_object_permissions(self.request, obj)
    return obj
```

`check_password` returns `False`. However, passing in the encoded password as the raw string password works. So hashing the password works, but not comparing the raw password to it after the fact.

Comment: You should use check_password() with user obj.


if obj.check_password(self.request.data['password']):
    raise Http404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if not check_password(self.request.data['password'], obj.password):
        raise Http404
```

change the line to the above code

Comment: over a year of Django programming and I made a blunder like that. Sometimes you just need a second pair of eyes. Thanks much